# my program wont solve for odd functions?

Tags: python, math, physics

i finally got this bit of code to "work" it works great for even powered functions. how ever it wont give any answer for odd powered functions.

i'm tracking the position of an object as it moves along a curve. i seems
to be giving me good data. but it wont terminate for odd powered functions.

i'm using python 3.5

```
import sympy
from sympy import *
from numpy import *
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = Symbol('x')

FuncY = input("Enter a function: Y(x) = ") 


F = sympy.sympify(FuncY)  

###################  Defined Variables   ########################

Vo = 0

Xo = -3

Yo = F.subs(x,Xo)

Xf = 3

Yf = F.subs(x,Xf)

A = -10

t = .01


Xi = Xo

Yi = Yo

Vi = Vo


XI = []

YI= []

VI = []
#########################


while Xi <= Xf:        


    dy_dx = float(F.diff(x).subs(x,Xi)) #derive function F


    theta = float(atan(dy_dx)) # find angle of slope


    a = A *  sin(theta) # find acceleration along curve


    V = Vi + a*t # find velocity along curve

    Vi = V # update initial velocity

    VI.append(Vi)
    ##################### position and velocity in X


    Vx = V*cos(theta) # velocity in x


    X = Xi + Vx*t # new position of do to velocity

    Xi = X

    XI.append(Xi)


###################################    position and velocity in y

    Vy = V*sin(theta)


    Y = Yi + Vy*t

    Yi = Y

    YI.append(Yi)


################################# 


print(XI)   

print(YI)
print('Velocity')
print(VI)

plt.plot(XI, YI,'bo')


plt.show()
```

thank you all for your help

chris

Comment: probably because Xi  is always <= Xf, print the values in your while and it will be pretty obvious

Comment: well i'm just dumb lol thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a lot of extra work to reconstruct the function; why not let sympy do it instead?

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

XMIN, XMAX, DATAPOINTS = -3., 3., 100

# get a recognizable equation (in terms of x)
x = sp.Symbol('x')
while True:
    try:
        s = input("Enter a function: Y(x) = ") 
        y = sp.sympify(s)
        break
    except sp.SympifyError as se:
        print(se)

# generate points to plot        
xs = np.linspace(XMIN, XMAX, DATAPOINTS)
ys = [y.evalf(subs={"x":xval}) for xval in xs]

# plot points
plt.plot(xs, ys, 'bo')
plt.show()
```

Comment: i have to run it with respect to time. not by breaking the x range in to intervals. you get similar answers but for some paths i need to track x wont change. which is why im going to expand it to a set of parametric  equations.

Comment: ... So, a pair of equations, x(t) and y(t)? Or are you going to try an implicit solver?

Comment: i'd use a pair of equations because i'll be able to get more complex paths. and i can track the change in x and y independently so that i can find the distance traveled  by the object even  when moving vertically.